# Django filter problem with date calculation

Tags: django, django-models

Django model has birth_year, birth_month, birth_day and death_year, death_month, death_day fields.

model.py

```
class person(models.Model):
   birth_year = models.SmallIntegerField()
   birth_month = models.SmallIntegerField()
   birth_day = models.SmallIntegerField()
   death_year = models.SmallIntegerField()
   death_month = models.SmallIntegerField()
   death_day = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

I have to get the count of persons who lives less than 1 month.

views.py

```
return render(request, 'report.html', {'count': count})
```

how can I query in view.py

I hope django expert's help. :)

Comment: add `count` query

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have separate fields for date components instead of a `DateField`?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
yes, I have to use the current fields. Because I have to upgrade django website and it already has those fields.

Comment: the fact the db schema has been improperly designed does not mean you can't fix it...

Answer (score 3):

> I have to get the count of persons who lives less than 1 month.

Use [`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

```
class Person(models.Model):
  birth = models.DateField()
  death = models.DateField()
```

You can use [`F` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to do the calculation, like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import F

q = Person.objects.annotate(life_span=F('death') - F('birth'))
                           .filter(life_span__lte=timedelta(days=29))
                           .count()
print(f'Number of people {q}')
```

Here I am assuming anyone who lives less than 29 days to have lived for less than a month.

The concept of a "month" differs based on leap years, etc. If you need that kind of precision, you can add some more filters and logic to the above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I have to use those fields existing in current website.
Is there any way to solve it using those fields?

Comment: Can I make a filter to create date from year, month, date?
Can I use datetime.date function?

Comment: I run your code, but following error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'life_span' into field. Choices are: ....

Comment: Ah you need to annotate first then filter.

Comment: I try that.
But there's an type error like this.

get_lookup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lookup_name'